# Why is the dataset taking too long to load?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, data-science, psycopg2

This is the only datatset i was able to find with the relevant information i needed. I am not able to load them as it is taking super long to be loaded. I have been waiting for 3 hrs and it is still not running. Am i doing anything wrong?

````
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mpcolours
import random
import math
import time
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

plt.style.use('seaborn')
%matplotlib inline

import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host='covid19db.org',
    port=5432,
    dbname='covid19',
    user='covid19',
    password='covid19')
cur = conn.cursor()


source = "GBR_NIDH"

sql_command = """SELECT * FROM epidemiology WHERE source = %(source)s ORDER by date DESC"""
df_epidemiology = pd.read_sql(sql_command, conn, params={'source': source}) ```
````

Comment: I guess it is not the data download that is taking so long, but it's already establishing the connection that does not work. I assume that the line `conn = psycopg2.connect(...)` that takes the time. There might be many reasons for this, firewall blocking access, database overloaded of offline, ...
You might be better of downloading daily extracts from https://github.com/covid19db/data

Comment: @divingTobi Initially i got them from  url you suggested but now i am unable to retrive any data from the url. When i tried to load the URL, there is no data as it has beem moved to git lfs. So this was the only way. Is there any other way i can extract the info? Thank you so much